# WSO2 API MANAGER clustering Worker-Manager

Tags: postgresql, api, wso2, api-manager

This is regarding WSO2 API Manager Worker cluster configuration with external Postgres db. I have used 2 databases i.e wso2_carbon for registry and user management and the wso2_am, for storing APIs. Respective xmls have been configured. The postgres scripts have been run to create the database tables. My log console when wso2server.sh is run, shows enabled clustering and the members of the domain. However on the https://: when I try to create to create APIs, it throws and error in the design phase itself.

```
 ERROR - add:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while checking whether context exists
[2016-12-13 04:32:37,737] ERROR - ApiMgtDAO Error while locating API: admin-hello-v.1.2.3 from the database
java.sql.SQLException: org.postgres.Driver cannot be found by jdbc-pool_7.0.34.wso2v2
```

Comment: Your classpath is apparently missing the postgres driver?

Comment: Nope. I have my postgres driver in the lib folder. And my driver name has been clearly set to  org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: Yes, and it clearly cannot be found.

Answer (score 0):

As per the error message, the driver class name you have given is `org.postgres.Driver` which is not correct. It should be `org.postgresql.Driver`. Double check `master-datasource.xml` config.